# Show that the point $(0,0)$ is an accumulation point of the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of an accumulation point states, an accumulation point of set $A$ is any point $x$ such that any open set containing $x$ also contains some point of $A$ other than $x$.

Here is what I have so far:
Let $x = (0,0)$. For any open ball, $B_r(x)$ for some $r>0$, there exists $y \in A$ and $y \in B_r(x)$.

I am not sure if I should pick an explicit point to prove $(0,0)$ is an accumulation point. I know there are infinitely many points getting closer and closer to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Equivalently, you need to build a sequence ${x_n}$ such that $x_n\in A, \forall n$, and $x_n\to(0,0)$ for $n\to\infty$. You can pick any such sequence, so pick a really simple one.

Comment: Would the sequence xn= 1/n for all N work? That is 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4...

Comment: Yes, that's arguably the simplest one. I wrote $x_n$ in the comment, but I should have wrote a clearer $P_n=(x_n,y_n)$, to avoid confusion.

Comment: So, the sequence Pn=(1/n,1/m) for n,m ∈ N  will converge to (0,0). But I am still confused how to show it is an accumulation point

Comment: That's it, you're done! To show that $(0,0)$ is an accumulation (or limit) point, you need to show that there is a sequence entirely contained in the set, whose limit is $(0,0)$.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AccumulationPoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly point an element both in $B_{r}(x)$ and $A$ to show that $x = (0,0)$ is an accumulation point. This is easier if you separate the cases when $r > 1$ and when $0 < r \leq 1$.

Comment: thank you , so when r>1, the entire circle  x^2 +y^2 ≤ 1 is contained in the ball Br(x) and when 0<r<1 the point (1/2, 1/3) is contained in Br(x) and in A.

Comment: When $ r > 1$ it is trivial as you point it. But imagine that $r = \frac{1}{4}$, then would the point $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}\right)$ be in $B_{r}(x)$? Look for a point that depends on $r$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What happens if, for any $0<r<1$ we take the point $(0,\frac{r}{2})$? Is it in $B_r(x)$?

Comment: yes that point is in the ball... which shows that (0,0) is an accumulation point